# How do I hide and unhide a floating button in UiViews within the scrolling view?

Tags: objective-c, view, uiscrollview

I want to load some views using a scroll view. I have 6 views in my view controller and one floating button. In my first view I don't want to show the floating button and in the remaining views I want to show it. I'm loading views like this:

```
-(void)loadViews
{
    for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<self.arrayViews.count; i++)
    {
        UIView *view = [self.arrayViews objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect frame =view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * i;
        view.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
        floatBtn.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Here i added like this

[image]

In MYPROFILE tab i don't want to show floating button.

In this screen i want to show floating button.

[image]

Comment: @honk. thank you for edit.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You seem to never want to show your button. Also, you set `arrayViews.count` times the same `floatBtn` to hidden.

Comment: The OP needs to explain how the `floatBtn` is created. Is this button one per view? There is no clue in the question about what's really expected. I suspect he wants that one unique button (detached from subviews) hidden when the first view is visible in the scrollview, and visible otherwise...

Comment: @Xvolks. see my updated question

Comment: So, when you change from My profile to Education view, there is an event (button click, network request, ...). In that event, call a delegate method to hide or show the button. Do you use storyboards or XIB ?

Comment: @Xvolks. i am using main view controller is a story board and loading views are xibs.

Comment: So the button belongs to the Storyboard ?

Comment: @Xvolks. created through story board.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107741/discussion-between-user558-and-xvolks).

Answer (score 0):

So you have a view controller like this (swift syntax) with a button.
You have to manage the hidden state of your button by code and call a method like selectView each time you want to change the visible view.

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet var floatBtn:UIButton!

     override func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)
         self.loadViews()
         self.selectView(0)
     }

     //your loadViews method
     func loadViews() { 
        //remove your floatBtn.hidden = YES; line here
     }

     func selectView(viewIndex:Int) {
         // do stuff to show your view
         self.mySubViewChanged(viewIndex != 0)
     }


     //create a method that will be called when an event triggers the subview change
     func mySubViewChanged(needsButton:Bool) {
        floatBtn.hidden = !needsButton
     }
}
```